# How can I show PowerPoint presentations (ppsx files) in a Moodle course page

Tags: php, powerpoint, moodle

I am using moodle 3.0 version.
And I am trying to preview presentation on my moodle page but its not gets view. 
I have uploaded my presentation on google and give path to preview it but it was not get view.

Comment: You want to show the slides of a powerpoint file in a moodle course ? Or you want to link a powerpoint file in your moodle course to allow the students to download it?

Comment: I want to show the slides of a powerpoint file in a moodle course  which student can see but not yo download it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Powerpoint to HTML converter.

I use [ISpring converter](http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ispring-converter) which has a [free version](https://www.ispringsolutions.com/ispring-free) with some banners on the resultant HTML slides.

It's a plugin which installs on your Powerpoint. You should start the conversion of the powerpoint file to HTML, Flash or Video within this addon.

It generates SCORM 1.2 compliant courses too.

I used with with lots of Powerpoint files, and I neved had one error in the conversion. Fonts, colors, images, ... all are very good translated to HTML without any problem in the positions or other things.

To add it to your Moodle, you should upload the converted powerpoint HTML to your server. In my moodle I use the "add URL resource" in the course editor. It's like one iFrame where you loads the converted powerpoint. Remember to create an .htaccess file to avoid hotlinking outside your Moodle.

Think about it's not possible at 100% to prevent experts users to download your course slide by slide.